# Print rows where one column is the same but another is different

Tags: awk

Given files `test1` and `test2`:

```
$ cat test*
alert_name,id,severity
bar,2,1
foo,1,0
alert_name,id,severity
foo,1,9
bar,2,1
```

I want to find rows where name is the same but severity has changed (ie `foo`) and print the change. I have got this far using awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} FNR>1 && NR==FNR { a[$1]; next } ($1 in a) && ($3 != a[$3]) {printf "Alert %s severity from %s to %s\n", $1, a[$3], $3}' test1 test2
```

which prints:

```
Alert foo severity from  to 9
Alert bar severity from  to 1
```

So the match is wrong, and I can't print `a[$3]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this `awk`:

```bash
awk -F, '$1 in sev && $3 != sev[$1] {
   printf "Alert %s severity from %s to %s\n", $1, sev[$1], $3
}
{sev[$1] = $3}' test*

Alert foo severity from 0 to 9
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like that works! Can you explain why we don't first need to assign `sev` with the syntax `NR==FNR{a[$1];next}`?

Comment: `NR==FNR` block is required when we need to store values from file1 only. Here we are processing multiple files and want to print a difference between each file.

Comment: If there are 2 input files only then you can use: `awk -F, 'NR==FNR{sev[$1] = $3; next} $1 in sev && $3 > sev[$1] {printf "Alert %s severity from %s to %s\n", $1, sev[$1], $3}' test*` as well.

Comment: Why `$3 > sev[$1]` instead of `$3 != sev[$1]`?

Comment: I just made an assumption that only increased severity would generate this alert. But fixing it now, Thanks Ed

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> mawk 'BEGIN { _+=(_^=FS=OFS=",")+_ } 
>       FNR == NR || +$_<=+___[__=$!!_] ? !_*(___[$!!_]=$_) : \
>       $!_ = "Alert "__ " severity from "___[__]" to " $_' files*.txt
> ```

```
Alert foo severity from 0 to 9
```